# Using .Net Core project with Web Forms projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms

I am about to maintain an old Web application that has WebForms projects. I need to add a new project to the application. Can it in any way be an MVC Core project? I mean, can an MVC Core project co-exist in the same application with WebForms projects?

Comment: one [not so great] workaround is to have separate projects for your .net core side and webforms side within the same solution. You'd then be able to render any of your webform pages inside an `<iframe src='your/path/to/view.aspx'>` in any of your other views. I think I'd only recommend this if rebuilding teh webforms side was completely out of the question and you had a good reason to not continue using webforms

Comment: You need to understand the difference between ASP.NET Core MVC, ASP.NET Core, ASP.NET, and .NET Framework. ASP.NET Core MVC runs on top of ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Core can run on top of .NET Framework or on top of .NET Core. ASP.NET runs only on .NET Framework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ASP.NET Core does not support WebForms and the Microsoft Team has said they have no plans to port webforms to asp.net core.  So no, you can't make an old webforms project into a asp.net core project.

Comment: Can you please provide Microsoft link that you mentioned as "no plan to port"

Comment: any updates on my questions? @Peter Kellner

Comment: There is a port in GitHub, please vote it https://github.com/CoreWebForms/CoreWebForms/issues/59 - something is moving

Answer (score 5):

If you are hosting your Web Forms application in Internet Information Services (IIS) you can create a separate project for MVC Core stuff and achieve the effect of hiving one application by adding the MVC Core application as a sub application in IIS Manager.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Right click the Web Forms site and select "Add Application..."
3. Select the folder you published your Core MVC application to as the "Physical path".
4. In the alias, enter the base path you want to use for the MVC stuff.

Comment: simple but elegant solution!